# Does the Office JS add-in will not be available for downloading from AppSource if we submit its version update on some date in the future?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-store

I've found the following data in the [Microsoft AppSource submission FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/appsource-submission-faq) - "If your submission is an update and you schedule the availability of your add-in to a date in the future, your existing add-in will be unpublished from Microsoft AppSource until the release date you specified."

Does it mean that if we already have the published add-in with the version 1.0 in AppSource in September, and we submitted for the version update to 1.1 in October, our add-in with v.1.0 will be unpublished and will not be available for download until October? So, the users who wants to download the add-in could not download it starting from the moment of the new version approval by the Store Team and until October?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an already published offer and submit an update with a **specific** release date for the update; then the published offer would be removed from Microsoft AppSource and storefronts until that date.

If you do not specify a release date for your update, then the already published version of your offer will not be affected. Once the update passes validation, it would replace the existing version with no break in availability.